# Loading Taxonomy image field in D7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I created an image field in a vocabulary called field_category_image.  It does not show up when I load the tree.

After a little digging, I came across field_get_items(), hoping this would work.  It does not though.  This is what I tried:

$category_image = field_get_items('taxonomy_term', $term, 'field_category_image');

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access empty property in /var/www/demo/public_html/modules/field/field.multilingual.inc on line 275
```

How do I get the value of the image field I added to my vocabulary?

Comment: are you trying to add the image to the display at `admin/structure/taxonomy/taxonomy_name`?

Comment: yes, i added the image field here: `admin/structure/taxonomy/category/fields`. When loading the vocabulary terms via: `$terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vid);`, the additional fields I add are not available in the term objects it returns.

Comment: Try setting the `$load_entities` parameter to true?

Comment: wow, i entirely overlooked that.  post it as an answer :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If loading the vocabulary terms as using [`taxonomy_get_tree`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/7) function, remember to set the `$load_entities` parameter to true.